# Chapter's title page before every chapter, and every chapter with its title

Tags: header-footer, titles, chapters

I am doing a research work and I googled half an hour and found nothing about this. Is there some way to get a title page (without any style) for every chapter?
I think the "without style" thing is done with `\thispagestyle{empty}`

Comment: By title page you mean something like the LaTeX \part in `book` document style?

Comment: @m0nhawk: what?

Comment: I mean something like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/WR9oa.png). Is this what you want?

Comment: @m0nhawk: yes but without numbering.

Comment: If I understand you right _(in fact I have difficulties in understanding, what you want, but this may be a lack in my knowledge of English language)_ a `\thispagestyle{empty}\cleardoublepage` directly after `\chapter{…}` should do, what you want. If yes, there are ways for automatic application of these macros …

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this with the help of [`titlesec`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) package:

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleclass{\chapter}{page}
\assignpagestyle{\chapter}{empty}
\titleformat{\chapter}
    [display]
    {\centering\Huge\bfseries}
    {\chaptername\ \thechapter}
    {0pt}
    {\huge}
    [\clearpage]

\begin{document}
    \chapter{First}
    \lipsum[10-20]
    \chapter{Second}
    \lipsum[10-20]
\end{document}
```

Additional formatting can be done via modifying the `\titleformat` options, see `#3.1` in [`titlesec`](ftp://ftp.tpnet.pl/pub/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/titlesec/titlesec.pdf) package manual.

And the result:

**Chapter page:**
[image]

**And text page:**
[image]