# Add a page with chapter name before every new chapter

Tags: sectioning, chapters

I want to add a page with Chapter number and Name before every chapter in like in image 1.

I tried the way specified in answer by m0nhawk on [this link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89761/chapters-title-page-before-every-chapter-and-every-chapter-with-its-title) but I have added few pages using `\chapter*` like dissimilar, acknowledgement etc. and that code is giving error to this. Also, It adds this page before like TOC, List of Figures etc. which is not useful for me.

One more thing, using the answer from above link, it removes chapter number and name from content page also, which is necessary for me. What I want is check below image :

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DUdfH.jpg]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IVpyK.jpg]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on our [our starter page](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code gave me this final output:

[image: First page]

[image: Second page]

Is it what you were looking for?

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{}
\chead{TITLE OF THESIS}
\rhead{}
\lfoot{}
\cfoot{}
\rfoot{\thepage}

\newcommand{\mychapter}[1]{\newpage%
\topskip0pt%
\vspace*{\fill}%
\addtocounter{chapter}{1}%
\begin{center}%
\textbf{\Large{\color{red}{CHAPTER NO. \thechapter \\ \uppercase{#1}}}}%
\end{center}%
\vspace*{\fill}%
\newpage%
\textbf{\Large{\thechapter. #1}}%
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}%
}

\begin{document}
\mychapter{Title of the first chapter}
\end{document}
```

Note: You can modify the sizefont or style to your will by modifying the adequate lines in the definition of the new command.

**EDIT:** The following has been added in order to fix some numbering problems occurring with the previous code. The disadvantage is that you need to load the `oneside` option of the `book` class in order to avoid to have the red chapter name on an odd page and the "regular" black chapter name on the following odd page (with the even page in between white). To finish the job you just need to check your headers and maybe redefine them using the tips in the [documentation](http://distrib-coffee.ipsl.jussieu.fr/pub/mirrors/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/fancyhdr/fancyhdr.pdf).

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\Huge\bfseries}{\thechapter.\hspace{15pt}}{0pt}{\Huge\bfseries}

\newcommand{\mychapter}[1]{\newpage%
\topskip0pt%
\vspace*{\fill}%
\addtocounter{chapter}{1}%
\begin{center}%
\textbf{\Large{\color{red}{CHAPTER NO. \thechapter \\ \uppercase{#1}}}}%
\end{center}%
\vspace*{\fill}%
\addtocounter{chapter}{-1}
\newpage%
\chapter{#1}
}

\begin{document}
\mychapter{Title of the first chapter}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is very good solution Ludovic, but my problem is my complete document is ready. So if I am changing to this then it is affecting to all sections and subsections numbers as well as header which contains chapter name added by `\fancyhead`.  Is there any way to redefine `\chapter` with this style ?

Comment: I don't see what is the problem with the numbers. just add a `\hspace{-0.55cm}` before `\thechapter. #` to get a better alignment with the sections and subsections numbers.

Comment: I am getting continuous section numbers from previous chapter like if 1.5 is last section of 1st chapter than in 2nd chapter section is starting from 2.6

Comment: Ok I would then suggest you to try what is explained in my edit.

Comment: It worked thank you. I not just have to work on header / footers. Is it possible to remove header footers from this page?

Comment: `\thispagestyle{empty}` ?