# Creating separate title page for each new section

Tags: header-footer, packages, titlesec, article, section-titles

I am new to LaTeX and I am writing my thesis atm.

I want to have a separate title page for each new section where it states the Section number, title and a few lines explaining the contents of the section. I have google'd around but can only find solutions for people using documentclass `book/report`. But I am using documentclass article. I have also tried using `\usepackage{titlesec}`.

I want to have it like this:
[Chapter's title page before every chapter, and every chapter with its title](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89761/chapters-title-page-before-every-chapter-and-every-chapter-with-its-title)

I have tried using the following code in my `main.tex` but it gave error as I could not use the `\chapter` commands and I tried to substitute them with `\section` but it did not work.

```
\titleclass{\chapter}{page}
\assignpagestyle{\chapter}{empty}
\titleformat{\chapter}
    [display]
    {\centering\Huge\bfseries}
    {\chaptername\ \thechapter}
    {0pt}
    {\huge}
    [\clearpage]
```

Help is much appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could you post a *complete* code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}` which reproduces the problem?

Comment: Hi @bakayaru, please provide a MWE. [Check this](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/140133) to understand what people ask you about. It is hard to help without knowing exactly what is causing the problem. Mainly which class and packages you are using.

Comment: If you are writing a thesis then `book` is a much better choice of document class than article. In you insist on using `\documentclass{article}`  but please post a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) so that people can see your setup.

Comment: You should use a `book class (book, scrbook, memoir) and change  `\section`s  to  `\chapter`s  and `\subsection`s to `\sections`, ... and probably use also \part for the first level.

Comment: This is what I have:

\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, titlepage]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[swedish]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{nameref}
\usepackage{enumitem}